# Ansible 'ini_file' module not creating file if not exists

Tags: ansible

Ok, so I need to update a flag inside the config file `etc/letsencrypt/dnscloudflare.ini` with a new value, and also create the aforementioned file if it doesn't exist already.

So I wrote the task with the [ini_file module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ini_file_module.html) as below,

```
- name: Update the "letsencrypt cloudflare plugin"'s config
  ini_file:
    path: /etc/letsencrypt/dnscloudflare.ini
    section: null
    option: "dns_cloudflare_api_key"
    value: "my-key-here"
    mode: 0600
    backup: yes
    create: yes
  become: yes
  become_user: root
```

Now, the file isn't there by default, so it should be created in the process but No matter what I do, the file **just doesn't get created**.

Note: I found [this bug report](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/30599), solution for which at the moment is still not merged.

So, as a work around I am now manually creating a file and then updating that file in the next task.

So

1. Why is this happening, like am I missing something?
2. Is there any known solution to this for the moment?

Comment: Did you try the [workaround mentioned here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/30599#issuecomment-348710188)? I haven't used this module, but am interested in your results.

Comment: Yup, tried it, I almost tried all the permutation & combinations of the modules parameters possible (well figuratively) :D but tell you what, that module is buggy as ***.

Comment: Might do better with `lineinfile`, though that's technically still preview. `replace` is `stableinterface`,  and its `others` takes all `file` arguments so you could theoretically use `state: touch`. If I get a minute I'll try this.

Comment: Nope. `"msg": "Unsupported parameters for (replace) module: state. Supported parameters include: attributes,backup,content,delimiter,directory_mode,follow,force,group,mode,owner,path,regexp,remote_src,replace,selevel,serole,setype,seuser,src,unsafe_writes,validate"` When the docs say "others | 
All arguments accepted by the file module also work here." they lie...or, maybe I just did it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [documented bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/30599) and the discussion is on-going as of 29-JUN-2018.

So as an alternative for the time being, you can copy a dummy file (if not present) with the same filename then proceed to update it or you can go ahead with using other file modification modules like [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html).